# numpy tensor log_prob() float presicion bug

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Working in pytorch, calculating the stdev or log_prob of a tensor gives incosistent results when using the default float32s. Example:

```
a=torch.tensor(np.repeat(3,10))
print(a)
print(a.log().std())
b=torch.tensor(np.repeat(3,5))
print(b)
print(b.log().std())
```

Output:

```
tensor([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
tensor(1.2566e-07)
tensor([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
tensor(0.)
```

What's the best way to make sure this is consistent? Manually defining a new log_prob function thar replaces tiny values with 0? I dont want to use float16 or worse presicion.

Since deviation should be 0, expected output should be exactly 0

Answer (score 0):

How about using `torch.round`?

The example below is rounded to 6 decimal places.

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
a=torch.tensor(np.repeat(3,10))
print(a)
print(torch.round(a.log().std(), decimals = 6))
b=torch.tensor(np.repeat(3,5))
print(b)
print(torch.round(b.log().std(), decimals = 6))
```

Output:

```py
tensor([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
tensor(0.)
tensor([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
tensor(0.)
```